# Finding Potential Function

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

Till now I have derived potential equation like in the picture shown below.
[image]

But now i stumbled upon derivation of potential for coaxial cable where the minus sign is not there in front of the equation.
[image]

I would like to know the reason why it works there without a minus sign.

Is it because of the definite integral or better say, that we have the two points to find out the potential difference?
Thank you.

Comment: This is a good question that I am sure has confused many. Since it is independent from coax or capacitance, perhaps you can generalize your title.

Comment: The way you labelled A and B the potential difference should be negative. Maybe in your book A and B are swapped, then potential difference is positive.  Note that \$U_{AB} = -U_{BA}\$. You are calculating the latter which has to be neagtive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a resource, refer to the German wikipedia page at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektrische_Spannung which I find a bit more illuminating than the English one at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage

Your top formula is for potential. In the form of a definite integral, it would be as follows:

[image]

(We are concerned with the conservative field, so omit the EMF portion with dA/dt)

Voltage is defined based on work required by an electron in an electrical field to move from A to B

[image]

which lines up with your bottom formula.

Putting the two together,

[image]